# how to render the pdf file to browser in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, browser, render

I have a `pdf document` in my `rails` application. i want to `render` this `pdf page` to the `browser`(not the downloading). i tried the following `code` but its not working, seems like the `hyperlink` is not making the request as `pdf` request. here is the `code`.

```
def read_more
    format.pdf do
    render :pdf => "/home/john/Downloads/read_more.pdf"
    end
end
```

and the link wchich makes apdf request is like this

```
<%= link_to 'Invoice', read_more_path, :format => :pdf %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add :disposition => :inline

```
def read_more
    respond_to do |format| 
       format.pdf do
          render :pdf => "/home/john/Downloads/read_more.pdf",
          :disposition => :inline
       end
    end 
end
```

and your link should be

```
<%= link_to 'Invoice', read_more_path(:format => :pdf) %>
```

Comment: the hyperlink is not making a pdf type of request. here is the terminal output.  Started GET "/read_more" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-04-12 16:16:06 +0530

Comment: I have updated it in case you forgot respond_to block and the link should be <%= link_to 'Invoice', read_more_path(:format => :pdf) %>